# 3D Graphing--finding an equation given a graph

Tags: conic-sections, 3d

I'm having trouble finding a reasonable equation for this graph:

http://i58.tinypic.com/15gtrn7.png

The x axis is the horizontal, y-axis is the axis coming out of the screen, the z-axis is vertical.

I don't need an exact equation, but a general, reasonable equation that is possible to make this graph. No specific points given.

It's hard for me to find an equation that dilates the paraboloid to be thinner along the y-axis.

It'd be nice if the equation was in the form of z^2-y^2-z^2=c, for example, where c is a nonzero constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the graph of
$$x^2 + y^2 -z^2 = -c^2$$
to me. You can see it by rewriting it as
$$x^2 + y^2 =z^2 -c^2$$
and observing the cross sections $z=\text{constant}$ (assume $c\geq 0$):

For $-c<z<c$, there is no solution, so the region between these planes doesn't meet the surface.

For $z=\pm c$, you get $x=y=0$, where the planes just are tangent to the tips of the surface.

For $z<-c$ or $z>c$, you get a circle of radius $\sqrt{z^2-c^2}$.

You can see, too, that sections by vertical planes $x=\text{constant}$ or $y=\text{constant}$  give hyperbolas that open upward and downward. There are no parabolic cross sections by any planes that I have mentioned.

Regarding dilation: just write
$$
\left(\frac xa\right)^2 + \left(\frac yb\right)^2 -\left(\frac zc\right)^2 = -1
$$
and you can scale any axis to your heart's content.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there any dilation to the equation? The paraboloids seem to be thin instead of expanding outwards on all sides at the same rate.

Comment: Edited my answer to include comment about dilation. Good?

Comment: Oh, yes that is helpful but in the graph that I attached a picture of, would the dilation be a large number on y?

Comment: In your picture, the surface is stretched outward in the $y$-direction, so take $b$ to be a large number relative to $a$ and $c$.